# Libraries for text classifiers such as SVM, KNN, and Naive Byes in JAVA?

Tags: java, classification, data-mining, svm, knn

Are there existing libraries for SVM, KNN, and Naive Bayes classifiers that I can use to classify TEXT. I need such libraries in my senior project and I don't have time to implement all of them.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like

1. [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)
2. [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/)
3. [Standford NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/downloads/)

I guess they are free for educational projects, better make sure license is not an issue for you.

Edit: Adding few more (Credit goes to Arun A K)

4) [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) (for SVM)

5) [Apache Mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/)

6) [Java ML Library](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Not sure if OpenNLP provides libraries for SVM